# Javascript window.open not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter, window.open

Ok. I'm trying to login to twitter. The window is not opening in this code. The response that gets alerted is not null and is a link to a login screen. Any ideas?

```
var url = "./twitter_login.php";
var con = createPHPRequest();

con.open("POST",url,true);
con.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
con.send("");

var response = "";

con.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if(con.readyState==4 && con.status==200) {

        response = con.responseText;    
        alert(response);
        window.open(response,"twitter","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=500");        

    }

}
```

Comment: Most browser block `window.open` if it's not associated with a user event (keyboard, mouse).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The standard popup-blocker logic contained in most browsers these days will block any calls to `window.open()` that are not the direct result of a user action.  Code that is triggered by timers or by any asynchronous callback (like your ajax ready function) will be treated as NOT caused directly by user actions and the new popup window will generally be blocked.

You can verify this is what is happening by temporarily changing your browser's popup blocking (turning it off) and see that it then starts working.

Probably what you need to do as a work-around is to create the window upon the user action that started this thread of code and then put the content into the window when you get your ajax response.  The browser will probably allow that.  I know that's less desirable from a visual perspective, but you can put some temporary content in the window until the ajax response comes in (something like "loading...").

Comment: Amazingly useful! Create a window on click with `window.open`, then pass it to your callback in which you'll do `mywindow.location = someurl`

Comment: What to do when I need to fire another ajax request? It's not working properly unless done via a user action.

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu - For us to help you, you would have to post your own question and show your own code.  There is no browser blocking of ajax calls via user action so that part does not make sense.  Let's not discuss here.  If you want further help, please post your own question.

Comment: wowwwww. was stuck on this for a while as it was working when tied to a user event but then I moved it into response block of an api call and it stopped working and didnt notice the little "popup blocked" in chrome. sure glad i found this, thought I was loosing it there for a bit

Answer (score 14):

Just had this exact same issue. Just in case you wanted the code that fixed it. I used this:

```
newWindow = window.open("", "_blank");

request = $.ajax({ ... my request which returns a url to load ... })

request.done((function(_this) {
        return function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          return newWindow.location = data.Url;
        };
      })(this));
```