# Open a Wordpress PHP redirection in a new tab

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, redirect

I am fairly new to web development. Currently, I am trying to solve the following problem: I am using Wordpress and the Woocommerce plugin for my website. I don't need the cart functionality from woocommerce so I decided to redirect the "Add to Cart" call action directly to the checkout page. This is possible for me using the following snippet in my function.php file.

```
function redirect_checkout_add_cart( $url ) {
  $url = get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_checkout_page_id' ) );
  return $url;
};
?>
```

However, I want the redirection/checkout page to be in a new tab (preferably not a new window). I tried to accomplish this by modifying the "redirect_checkout_add_cart" function

```
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_checkout_add_cart' );

function redirect_checkout_add_cart( $url ) {
  $url = get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_checkout_page_id' ) ); 
  ?> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var URL = '<?php echo $url; ?>';
  window.open(URL, '_blank')</script> ;
  <?php
}
?>
```

It succesfully opens a new tab with the redirection. However, somehow it messes up the styling from the page with the "add to cart" call to action button. Also, it does not feel like clean coding the way I did it right now but please forgive me as this is my first ever web coding project :).

Does anyone knows what is going wrong? Any sources/tips applicable to this problem are also welcome.

Comment: There are many things wrong here. This filter should return a URL. This filter will inject a <script> element into the HTML document when the filter is processed, which can be anywhere in the document depending on when the filter is invoked.  This script will automatically open a new page, i.e., not when the submit button is clicked. Further, the add to cart exists to put items in the cart. This cart is used to generate an order. If you skip the add to cart you must then generate the order yourself.

Comment: This can be done with a different approach but you really need a good understanding of how the WooCommerce plugin works. I would suggest studying WC_Checkout::create_order(). I don't think this is a project for a beginner but it can be done.

Comment: On further thought this is not that hard (but not easy) let the add to cart call the server to add the item to the cart as usual. Now that the cart is created with a single item instead of reloading the page redirect to checkout which can work properly since a cart has been created.

Comment: Thank you, Magenta. I am going to dive deeper into the plugin. I've found a solution for previous woocommerce versions which is not working for me (I am on woocommerce 3.1); https://pointclearmedia.com/2014/11/20/make-woocommerce-external-products-open-new-window/

Comment: I don't think that approach will solve your problem. Let make sure I understand your problem. You want to skip the cart step because there will always be only one item in the cart. Is this correct?

Comment: I will be returning to my real work and will not be back for a while. I want to leave you with these final hints: Read ...woocommerce\templates\checkout\review-order.php and WC_Checkout::create_order_line_items(). Then you will realize that the order items are created from cart items. If you skip the add to cart action and go directly to the checkout page the checkout page will not have any items since the cart is empty. So, I think it would be easier to do the add to cart action even if it is only 1 item and hide this action from the buyer.

Comment: That is correct. I understand that I cannot completely skip te cart. Thanks, will study it some more...

Answer (score 1):

First, I must apologize as some of my comments actually are not applicable. The filter 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect' is applied after the item is added to the cart so my comments about an empty cart is nonsense. In fact, your answer is not far from what will work. Here is my solution which has a problem that I will explain later.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', function( $url ) {
    static $done = false;
    if ( $done ) {
        return $url;
    }
    add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', function() {
?>
<script>
    window.open( '<?php echo wc_get_checkout_url(); ?>', '_blank' );
</script>
<?php
    });
    $done = true;
    return $url;
});
```

The critical change is I used the action 'wp_print_footer_scripts' to inject the JavaScript code in the page footer. My guess is that your code would inject the JavaScript code before the `<html>` tag. I also return the $url as required by the filter. The $done flag is there because this filter is called twice - it is a filter not an action so that is allowed. (We are actually abusing this filter by having a side effect.) However, when I tested this my browser [blocked it as a popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821009/javascript-window-open-not-working) which I had to manually unblock. I would consider redirecting the 'View Cart' button to a 'Go To Checkout' button instead.