# Javascript window.open works in Chrome console but not as a snippet

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm relatively new to Javascript and I'm working on some little scripts to modify webpages that I work with often. One of the things I'm automating is opening certain links in tabs and so I don't have to do so manually.

If I put this line into my snippet and run it, nothing happens:

```
window.open("http://www.google.com");
```

But if I type it into the console and hit return, it opens a new tab with the url just fine. All of this is happening in the Inspector. Why does it work in one place but not the other? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I see a notification in the address bar about a blocked pop-up. AFAIK this is the default behavior, but you can change it in the browser options.

Comment: You can refer to the explanation on this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821009/javascript-window-open-not-working

Answer (score 1):

When Chrome detects a call to `window.open()` which does not originate from a user gesture, it blocks it as a pop-up.

You can manually override this via the little Pop-Up modal that shows up on the right-edge of your URL bar:

[image: pop-up modal]

The interesting thing you brought up is: why does it work from the Console, but not from Snippets? I asked the DevTools team, and one of them informally thinks that DevTools treats Console execution as user gestures, to avoid security checks like these.

One workaround that may be good enough for you is to run your snippet from a new Chrome tab (`chrome://newtab`). When I run the Snippet from that page, I can open new windows without triggering the "Pop-up blocked" modal.

Thanks for experimenting between how it worked with Console and Snippets. That turned out to be pretty interesting.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this for me. It turns out, as you and  wOxxOm suggest, that "Allowing" pop up windows from the site in question fixes the problem. Once pop-ups are unblocked, snippets can open a tab just like I need them to.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `window.open` is kind of misleading. This is to the fact that `window` is the global context in JavaScript and `open` is a method within that object. You should not read it as "open a window".
Actually, it

> loads a resource into [...] a new browsing context (**such as** a window)

([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open))

Most modern browsers are tabbed, hence a *browsing contxt* is a tab and, following of that, they (mostly, but not always) would open a new tab rather than a window. What can you do? For example, code like

```
window.open('http://google.de', 'google', 'width=500,height=500')
```

actually opens a *window* for me (Chrome 59). However, it might get blocked as a popup by the browser.