# Chrome console: snippet command can't open dialog

Tags: javascript, dialog, console, google-chrome-devtools, code-snippets

I have a simple oneline snippet to "click" on a «load file» button on a visible page to call a dialog-popup (to load an image, for example).

```
this.document.getElementsByName("image")[0].click()  // snippet code
```

While **manual** paste and run this line in console is successful (it opens the dialog), the above snippet can't do that. Seems like Chrome doesn't allow to open dialog not by user call. So, I set browser to allow all popups but there is no result.

Tested on different pages where file load button presents.

Thanks for any ideas.

[A similar but different issue, solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45331065/javascript-window-open-works-in-chrome-console-but-not-as-a-snippet)

Answer (score 0):

> Seems like Chrome doesn't allow to open dialog not by user call.

I created a snippet to test if this statement is true. It seems like it is incorrect.

1. Click the **Run Snippet** button in this answer.
2. Open DevTools.
3. Click [**Inspect**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/reference#select) and click the image that says `350x150`.
4. Evaluate `document.querySelector('img').click()` in the Console. The text below the image increments.
5. Run the same statement from a Snippet. The text still increments.

```js
document.querySelector('img').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let p = document.querySelector('p');
  p.textContent = parseInt(p.textContent) + 1;
});
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/>
<p>0</p>
```

Possible solutions:

- Make sure that you are in the correct Console context when you run the snippet. See [Selecting Execution Context](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/#execution-context).
- The use of `this` in your statement might be causing problems. Try removing it.
- Try adding an ID to your element and then referencing it by its ID, rather than the `getElementsByName` array. So, use `document.getElementById('myCustomId').click()` instead. Make sure to add the ID to the HTML element, e.g. `<img id="myCustomId" .../>`. It's possible that you're referencing the wrong element, so that's why you're seeing the wrong result when you execute `click()`.

Add comments to this answer and we'll eventually figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunatelly nothing was successful in my case. I've tried that on different machines (Win 7 and 10, latest Chrome ver.). I've checked the Context, changed the ID to unique "myID123", varied the prefix "this." Everything works directly by manual pasting the string .click() in the Console but nothing of that works by running in snippet.

I've also checked your script with a image. This works fine both from console and from snippet.

The command .click() calls a file-load dialog. May be something is wrong with restrictions?

Comment: Can you link me to what page you’re testing with?

Comment: This is my site CMS page initially. But, of course, we could use any page where a file should be loaded by clicking on button to call standard loading dialog. I'll try google images, for example.

Comment: upd: I've checked Google Images button to upload image. The same, snippet doesn't work. In my case the code is: `document.getElementById("qbfile").click()`