# Why won't a JavaScript alarm work when not in an active tab?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to create a JavaScript alarm for a school schedule. The alarm works perfectly when I am on that CodePen tab, but does not execute when I am on a different tab(still in that window). A codepen is [here](https://codepen.io/swishnflick/pen/bYVXqy). It uses the date object in JavaScript. The variable day is for different schedules- we have an abbreviated schedule on certain days and the alarm is set up to deal with that.

```
    var day;
  function choose(choice){
    day=choice;
  }
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
   var x=1;


window.setInterval(function(){ // Set interval for checking
    var date = new Date(); // Create a Date object to find out what time it is
if(day==1){
     document.body.style.background ="black";
  document.getElementById("number2").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("number1").style.display="block";
if(date.getHours()===8 && date.getMinutes
()===16&&date.getSeconds()==0){
 window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNpXCzaWW1s");

}
  if(date.getHours()===9 && date.getMinutes
()===10&&date.getSeconds()==0){
 window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNpXCzaWW1s");

}
   if(date.getHours()===10 && date.getMinutes
()===04&&date.getSeconds()==18){
 window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNpXCzaWW1s");

}
     if(date.getHours()===11 && date.getMinutes
()===36&&date.getSeconds()==0){
 window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNpXCzaWW1s");

}
  if(date.getHours()===12 && date.getMinutes
()===42&&date.getSeconds()==0){
  window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNpXCzaWW1s");

}
    if(date.getHours()===1 && date.getMinutes
()===24&&date.getSeconds()==0){
 window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNpXCzaWW1s");

}
    if(date.getHours()===2 && date.getMinutes
()===18&&date.getSeconds()==0){
  window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNpXCzaWW1s");

}}
  else if(day==0){
     document.getElementById("number1").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("number2").style.display="block";
    document.body.style.background ="white";
    if(date.getHours()===8 && date.getMinutes
()===9&&date.getSeconds()==0){
  window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNpXCzaWW1s");

}
  if(date.getHours()===8 && date.getMinutes
()===56&&date.getSeconds()==0){
   window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNpXCzaWW1s");

}
   if(date.getHours()===9 && date.getMinutes
()===45&&date.getSeconds()==0){
  window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNpXCzaWW1s");

}
     if(date.getHours()===10 && date.getMinutes
()===17&&date.getSeconds()==0){
 window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNpXCzaWW1s");

}
  if(date.getHours()===11 && date.getMinutes
()===08&&date.getSeconds()==0){
  window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNpXCzaWW1s");

}
    if(date.getHours()===11 && date.getMinutes
()===59&&date.getSeconds()==0){
 window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNpXCzaWW1s");
}
    if(date.getHours()===12 && date.getMinutes
()===46&&date.getSeconds()==0){
   window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNpXCzaWW1s");

}
```

Comment: The code as posted is incomplete. As implemented, it'll miss particular times if the timer does not go off precisely as scheduled, and such timers are definitely not guaranteed to be accurate. Browsers slow interval timers on inactive tabs way, way down.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I am on a different tab"? Is this the same browser tab, but a different tab display (div) on the displayed page?

Comment: [`setInterval` is throttled to 1000ms when not in an active tab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified), but since you don't appear to be using precision higher than 1 second anyway, that might not be the issue. My guess is your browser doesn't allow non-focused pages to use `window.open`. Does it work if you `alert` something instead of `window.open`?

Comment: @apsillers I'm somewhat perplexed that the browser would let a timer event loop use `window.open()` at all.

Comment: @Pointy me too, this seems like a pretty bad idea to use for this in general

Comment: How else could I implement this? @pointy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers aggressively block window.open, to prevent spam/popups/etc.

This might help you though:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11821617/3650835